# Best way to get a specific descendant relative to a Navigator Object

Tags: selenium, geb

Here is an example of the HTML I am working with:

```
<div //this is the Navigator I have
    <div
    <div class = 'myClass'
        <div
            <sort-table
                <table
                    <thead </thead>
                    <tbody </tbody> //this is the Navigator I want
                </table>
            </sort-table>
        </div>
    </div>
    ... (you get the idea)
```

I have a method that is supposed to grab the table relative to a specific Navigator. The Navigator in question is linked up to the div I have marked in the HTML above. and I want it to return the tbody.

I am surprised there is no getAllDecendents method for Navigator.

right now my method looks like this:

```
Navigator getTable(Navigator config){
        return config.children($(By.xpath("//div[@class='myClass']"))).children().children().children().children($(By.xpath("//tbody")))
    }
```

It works fine, but I don't like that I have to do the children() chain. I have to imagine there is simply a way to grab a descendant based on a particular selector but I can not find anything like that in the API

I should add there is a very good reason I don't just use xpath to grab that table. This is just a small snippet of the HTML. This same structure is duplicated many times on the page which is why I have the getTable method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of .children()?

$("div.myClass").find("tbody")

Comment: The Geb API does not really make the functionality of the find() method very clear. The link you provided cleared up all my confusion